# how to make a context aware code evaluator

Tags: raku

I was looking at REPL-like evaluation of code from [here](https://github.com/rakudo/rakudo/blob/master/src/core.c/REPL.pm6) and [here](https://github.com/Raku/nqp/blob/master/src/HLL/Compiler.nqp), and tried to make a very small version for it, yet it fails:

```
use nqp;

class E {

    has Mu $.compiler;
    has $!save_ctx;

    method evaluate(@fragments) {
        for @fragments -> $code {
            my $*MAIN_CTX;
            my $*CTXSAVE := self;

            $!compiler.eval($code,
                            outer_ctx => nqp::ctxcaller(nqp::ctx()));

            if nqp::defined($*MAIN_CTX) {
                $!save_ctx := $*MAIN_CTX;
            }
        }
    }

    method ctxsave(--> Nil) {
        say "*in ctxsave*";
        $*MAIN_CTX := nqp::ctxcaller(nqp::ctx());
        $*CTXSAVE := 0;
    }

}

my $e := E.new(compiler => nqp::getcomp("Raku"));
nqp::bindattr($e, E, '$!save_ctx', nqp::ctx());
$e.evaluate: ('say my @vals = 12, 3, 4;', 'say @vals.head');
```

I pieced together this from the above links without very much knowing what I'm doing :) When run, this happens:

```
*in ctxsave*
[12 3 4]
===SORRY!=== Error while compiling file.raku
Variable '@vals' is not declared.  Did you mean '&val'?
file.raku:1
------> say ⏏@vals.head
```

with Rakudo v2022.04. First fragment was supposed to declare it (and prints it). Is it possible to do something like this, so it recognizes `@vals` as declared?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do it in pure Raku code, although depending on the not-exactly-official `context` parameter to `EVAL`.

```
# Let us use EVAL with user input
use MONKEY;

loop {
    # The context starts out with a fresh environment
    state $*REPL-CONTEXT = UNIT::;
    
    # Get the next line of code to run.
    my $next-code = prompt '> ';

    # Evaluate it; note that exceptions with line numbers will be
    # off by one, so may need fixups.
    EVAL "\q'$*REPL-CONTEXT = ::;'\n$next-code", context => $*REPL-CONTEXT;
}
```

Trying it out:

```
$ raku simple-repl.raku
> my $x = 35;
> say $x;
35
> my $y = 7;
> say $x + $y;
42
```

Comment: wow thanks cant upvote yet but anyway, what does `$*REPL-CONTEXT = ::;` do in EVAL? i'm doing that in an arbitrary program and it hangs :) If you are already passing `context` why do you need to do that seemingly extra thing? documentation mentions its package separator but not like this as bare usage, not sure what it separates

Comment: also: if you do `> my $a = 1` and `> my $a = 2` in inputs separately one after another, it doesnt complain, why could this be

Comment: `::` on its own gives a `PseudoStash` that corresponds to the current lexical scope. The set of variables in a lexical scope is immutable after compile time in Raku, so really each new `EVAL` line is in a new lexical scope. We're arranging that the next `EVAL` happens such that its outer scope is that of the previous `EVAL`. This is also why you can declare a new `$a`: it's not a conflict because the new line is a new scope. The built-in REPL necessarily has the same semantics!

Comment: wuhuu, enlightened, thanks, last question: i did `> my $a = 1` and then immediately after it, `my $a = 2; OUTER::<$a>.say`; it says Nil. But if I do `OUTERS` instead of `OUTER`, it does say 1! So there is another scope in between i'm missing?

Comment: I believe it's an artifact of the current compiler implementation (it uses an extra frame outside that of the `UNIT` as an implementation detail).